# PowerMock Testcase failing randomly

Tags: mockito, junit4, powermockito

```
class A{
    public static methodToMock();

}

class B{
    public methodToTest_A(){
        ....
        ....
        A.methodToMock()
        ...

    }

     public methodToTest_B(){
        ....
        ....
        A.methodToMock()
        ...

    }
}

@PrepareForTest ({A.class })
@RunWith (PowerMockRunner.class)
TestB{

    shouldTestMethodToTest_A(){
        mockStatic(A.class);
        when(methodToMock()).thenReturn(someValue);
        ...

    }

    shouldTestMethodToTest_B(){
        mockStatic(A.class);
        when(methodToMock()).thenReturn(someValue);
        ...

    }

}

mvn test:surefire
//parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=4, useUnlimitedThreads=false, threadCountSuites=0, threadCountClasses=0, threadCountMethods=0, parallelOptimized=true
```

**This Test case if falling randomly.**

My initial finding: powerMock register classes in `MockRepository` and after every testcase it runs `MockitoStateCleanerRunnable` which clean state. 
It looked like they are affecting each other.
It looked like it might be falling because of running tests in parallel, which I can't disable.

Is I am missing something?

```
PowerMock:1.6.5
Mockito-core:1.10.19
```

Any Help Will be appreciated.

Comment: How exactly do you run them in parallel (I assume the classes run in parallel, not the methods)? And if you say they are failing, what does that mean (exception or just a failing assertion) ?